# Swift asynchronous function lag

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous, mapkit

I am experiencing issues when trying to call the `.calculate` function found in the iOS MapKit. I understand that this function runs on a separate thread than my main thread, but I do not know how to update the value of `walkingTime` before returning control to the main thread.

```
class RouteManager {

    static let shared = RouteManager()
    var initialWalkingTime: Double!
    var finalWalkingTime: Double!
    private init() {

    }

    func calculateWalkingTime(
                from givenLocation: CLLocation,
                to givenStop: CLLocation,
                completion: @escaping (_ double: Double?, _ error: Error?) -> () ) {

        let sourcePlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: givenLocation.coordinate)
        let sourceMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlacemark)
        let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: givenStop.coordinate)
        let destinationMapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
        var walkingTime: Double?

        let request = MKDirectionsRequest()
        request.source = sourceMapItem
        request.destination = destinationMapItem
        request.transportType = .walking
        request.requestsAlternateRoutes = false
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)

        directions.calculate { response, error in
            if let route = response?.routes.first {
                walkingTime = (route.expectedTravelTime/60)
            }
            completion(walkingTime, error)
        }
    }

    func setupRoutes(from initialLocation: CLLocation, to finalLocation: CLLocation) {

        let startingLocation = BusManager.shared.startingLocation.location
        let endingLocation = BusManager.shared.endingLocation.location

        calculateWalkingTime(from: initialLocation, to: startingLocation) {(walkingTime, error) in
            guard let walkingTime = walkingTime, error == nil else {return}
            self.initialWalkingTime = walkingTime
        }

        calculateWalkingTime(from: endingLocation, to: finalLocation) {(walkingTime, error) in
            guard let walkingTime = walkingTime, error == nil else {return}
            self.finalWalkingTime = walkingTime
        }
    }
}
```

Basically my `RouteManager.shared.initialWalkingTime` and `RouteManager.shared.finalWalkingTime` are used on my UI so I need them to be updated before they leave my `calculateWalkingTime` function.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the calculation short enough, it's probably fine to just nest them:

```
func setupRoutes(from initialLocation: CLLocation, to finalLocation: CLLocation) {

    let startingLocation = BusManager.shared.startingLocation.location
    let endingLocation = BusManager.shared.endingLocation.location

    calculateWalkingTime(from: initialLocation, to: startingLocation) {(firstWalkingTime, error) in
        guard let firstWalkingTime = firstWalkingTime, error == nil else {return}

        calculateWalkingTime(from: endingLocation, to: finalLocation) {(secondWalkingTime, error) in
            guard let secondWalkingTime = secondWalkingTime, error == nil else {return}
            self.initialWalkingTime = firstWalkingTime
            self.finalWalkingTime = secondWalkingTime
        }
    }
}
```

Note that with your design you should probably make `self.initialWalkingTime` and `self.finalWalkingTime` optionals because it's a fail-able process.

Comment: I believe the issue is more that the `.calculate` takes longer than the `calculateWalkingTime` function so when control gets back to the `setupRoutes` function it sets `initialWalkingTime` and `finalWalkingTime` to `nil` rather than my desired value.

Comment: That's not how this works...your `setupRoutes` function will finish before `calculateWalkingTime`'s completion block is ever called.

Comment: I guess my question is how would I get the value of `calculateWalkingTime` saved into `initialWalkingTime` and `finalWalkingTime` before `setupRoutes` is completed.